# Tracking the DML

Tags: apex

I have a custom object record C1.

It has a currency field Fee_Rate__c.

When I update this record from the standard page layout ..an another object (let us say R1) R1.Update__c flag is set to TRUE.

The strange thing is the object C1 has no trigger, WF, process builder or flow that can be used to track the DML event on it.

Can anyone tell me where I should be looking to find out which code or process is causing the update ???

I tried to look into the debug log. The debug log has no Apex footprint at all.

Comment: Are R1 and C1 related objects?

Comment: Expanding on David Reed's comment, if `R1` and `C1` have a master-detail relationship, and you're rolling up some data from `C1` to `R1`, then an update to `C1` will also cause an update to `R1`.  At any rate, remember that providing more details is usually better than providing fewer details. It's hard to discern your problem (and identify a solution) with what you've given us so far.